# Animate <hr> width on browser resize with css only

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to animate an hr width on page resize but it doesn't seem to work in any way. When the browser resizes the font resizes properly and the hr position with the font resizes properly too, but the width resizes instantly with the browser size. I achieved this behavior some time ago and now I just can't find out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the full page code so far:

```css
html,
body {
  background: #aaa;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: all 1s;
  font-size: calc(1.25vw + 1.75vh);
}

h1,
h3 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0%;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 1px;
  transition: width 2s ease;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.container {
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="container">
    <hr>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum.</h3>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah, I was waiting for this question! I know how to fix it (replace the width:100% by something using vw unit) but I don't know the reason ... as your question is: why transition works with vw/vh unit on resize and not with % values

Comment: Widths in percentages have a different type than widths with length units. They _are_ animatable, but only as percent values (so in this case they go from 100% to 100%!) while length units are calculated in pixels. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Specifications) mentions the two kinds of animation type.

Comment: @MrLister I guess it worth adding an answer to this ;) as I got the logic myself but not able to find it clearly written and explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mr Lister commented, the width of the **hr** can not be transitioned, since the property is not changing (it is always 100%). It doesn't matter that the **result** of this property changes !

The correct way to handle this is to set the transition in the element that really changes, the container. Well, it's true that it's value is always 50vw, but this is a special case that is handled by the browser with the equivalent value in pixels.

```css
html,
body {
  background: #aaa;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: all 1s;
  font-size: calc(1.25vw + 1.75vh);
}

h1,
h3 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0%;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 1px;
  transition: width 2s ease;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.container {
  width: 50vw;
  transition: width 2s ease;  /*   added */

}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="container">
    <hr>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum.</h3>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```